# How to programmatically access websites through Java? Download HTML code, save cookies, fill and send forms etc

Tags: java, android, web

Downloading a code of website is not a problem. However using this code not always is so simple.

I was wondering if there is any package, which makes it more easy to send HTTP GET/POST requests according to specified form. This will help perform a log-in to some websites, even using SSL.

I am sure that there are hundreds of programs which make such things possible. I was wondering what would be the best practices in this scope.

Comment: Pardon me, what is your real question? do you want a remote controller or what?

Comment: I've edited the question heavily. Please check if this is what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HttpUnit to programmatically examine a Web page, follow links, explore tables, work with forms, etc. See examples in the [HttpUnit Cookbook](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook.html).

Note: HttpUnit is meant for unit-testing, but perhaps it's OK for your purposes too.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul: sometimes it happens :)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the Java [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) library.

It even handles cookies and JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

see [Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga) from apache

Answer (score 0):

You dont use html for this. you need some kind of a webService... or show the page in a webView but still if you want something more with it either it needs to have a callback url or something which you can capture and extract from the url some params to use.

By the way i see android in the tags. is this actually an android question or its more general? i can't really tell what exactly are you looking for here.

Comment: I guess he would be glad to use an API but there is none available or something?

Comment: for parsing html look at this link: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers. but i don't think this will work for submitting. maybe if you could actually get the page and fill the fields with this and then submit it somehow. usually the stuff you are sending is encoded in the url (some standard http get usage or something like that) so maybe check the redirects for info in the url also.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) from [Selenium AndroidDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AndroidDriver), but I didn't tested it yet.